Business logic in any Programming languages
when they say  business logic of an application in programming what does that refer to?
I have heard alot of that and it's kind of confusing me, like I am late or am missing something when developping
I just need a clear explaination of that concept.

It is the logic (code) that implements what the business' product does.
Say you ran a website to rent out cars. You might have a "front end," i. e., the interface that the user interacts with.  The code that implements this GUI for the user should be ideally different than the one that figures out what cars are available and for how much.  The code that does the figuring out of availability and prices is "business logic."
In the vanilla Model View Control code architecture, (roughly speaking) the model is going to be your business logic.

Business logic is just a piece of code that defines some type of logic/rule that governs the application.
For example, in your application, a user fills out a form that contains a field age, and when the user submits the form a piece of code will run to apply some logic over it.
Let's say that application doesn't allow users below age 18 then that user will be unable to use the application. This condition of being below 18 is a part of business logic.
Another example can be that you are showing a list of products to the user and the user clicks on a button that sort it based on price. This sorting is a part of business logic.
